# Bootstrap - Can't click dropdown child menu items on mobile and first click not triggering nav-collapse

Tags: android, iphone, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I've run into two issues with dropdown menu items on mobile devices. Specifically:

1. My nav-collapse isn't shown on the first click of btn-navbar, but only on an iPhone.
2. While I can toggle dropdowns, I can't click on any dropdown-menu items on mobile devices.

My page is valid on W3 Validator and I have added both the .nav-collapse and .collapse classes to my navbar. Plus everything works fine when resizing the browser window on my laptop.

You can see the live web page here: http://hartmandashboard.com/

Has anyone seen this problem before? Anyone care to offer a potential fix? I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: I came across this myself, it's an issue with version 2.1.1, similar question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672889/twitter-bootstrap-subnav-closes-instead-of-activating-link-on-iphone. The issue on github is here - https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4497

Comment: Holy cow, this question was from last year, I just noticed that. My answer below might not be valid, we'll see.

Comment: Just tested this and it works well. I add it to the main bootstrap.css file.
I am also using Bootstrap 3

Answer (score 27):

Yes, I've seen this before and I saw the issue is on github as well. I don't remember exactly where I found this, but some guy was saying that it was an issue about setting those elements to `position: absolute;` and that re setting them to static would fix it.

So why don't you go ahead and try this on your custom CSS:

**CSS**

```
.dropdown-backdrop {
  position: static;
}
```

Let me know if we're on the same page and this solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This was initially a bootstrap problem.
See the fix here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9543