# Bootstrap navbar responsive dropdown doesn't respond to touch

Tags: android, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 to build a responsive site.  I have a navbar with dropdown menus:

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li  {% if request.get_full_path = "/" %} class="active" {% endif %} ><a href="/">Home</a></li>

        <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown" id="about"
        {% if request.get_full_path = "/about/" %} class="active" {% endif %}>
        <a href="/about/" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About
            <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="about">
            <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
            <li role="presentation">
                <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/news/"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

On a desktop browser, the drop down responds to a click, even if the window is resized to show the mobile view.  When I use my Nexus 4 using both Chrome & Dolphin Browser, the drop down links don't work.  The caret button works, when I click a dropdown link, the dropdown menu retracts and I am not redirected.  I haven't tried other mobile devices however.

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like known issue. However it shows closed on the github. I was having the same issue and found the solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902734/bootstrap-cant-click-dropdown-child-menu-items-on-mobile-and-first-click-not).

This solved my issue. You can try as well.