# Bootstrap 2.3 Collapsible menu issues in android mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I have been researching for a while now and could not find a solution for this nor any related question to my issue, So sorry if this was already asked before.

I'm developing a website using Twitter Bootstrap 2.3 and I have an issue with the collapsible menu component in Android (tested using Samsung Galaxy s4 with android 4.2 on Chrome latest version).

When I "uncollapse" the menu for the first time, the components works as expected, but if I collapse it, and then "uncollapse" it again, the links appear like "hidden". I can still touch them and the links work as expected. But nothing is displayed, as if they where transparent or something.

Did anybody experience an issue like this one? Any help would be appreciatted.

## I have found a solution to this. It is kinda rough though.

This was my html markup:

```
<div id="navContainer" class="nav-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse in collapse" style="height: auto;">
    <ul id="headerNav" class="nav green">
        <li class="active"><a class="headerLink" href="/es">El Pueblo</a></li>
        <li><a class="headerLink" href="#">Cómo llegar</a></li>
        <li><a class="headerLink" href="/es/noticias">Noticias</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Turismo <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu green" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
                <li role="presentation"><a class="headerLink" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/es/historia">Historia</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a class="headerLink" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Actividades</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a class="headerLink" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/es/info">Info General</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a class="headerLink" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/es/paseos">Paseos</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a class="headerLink" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Imágenes</a></li>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="headerLink" href="/es/mapas">Mapa Interactivo!</a></li>
        <li><a class="headerLink" href="#">Contacto</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop3" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Idioma <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul id="menu3" class="dropdown-menu green" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop3">
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/es/">Español</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/en/">English</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/de/">Deutsch</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>                    
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the fix that worked for me:

```
.nav-collapse { 
    -webkit-transform: none !important; 
    z-index: 1 !important; 
}
```

This issue was only present in Android using Chrome. On IOS the issue was not there

Comment: I've come across this before, check this solution>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902734

For future reference this type of navigation menu is called responsive navigation. This might help with future searches. Let me know how it goes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution to this. It is kinda rought thouth.

This was my html markup:

```
<div id="navContainer" class="nav-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse in collapse" style="height: auto;">
    <ul id="headerNav" class="nav green">
        <li class="active"><a class="headerLink" href="/es">El Pueblo</a></li>
        <li><a class="headerLink" href="#">Cómo llegar</a></li>
        <li><a class="headerLink" href="/es/noticias">Noticias</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Turismo <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu green" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
                <li role="presentation"><a class="headerLink" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/es/historia">Historia</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a class="headerLink" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Actividades</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a class="headerLink" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/es/info">Info General</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a class="headerLink" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/es/paseos">Paseos</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a class="headerLink" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Imágenes</a></li>
             </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="headerLink" href="/es/mapas">Mapa Interactivo!</a></li>
        <li><a class="headerLink" href="#">Contacto</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop3" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Idioma <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul id="menu3" class="dropdown-menu green" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop3">
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/es/">Español</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/en/">English</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="/de/">Deutsch</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>                    
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the fix that worked for me:

```
.nav-collapse { 
    -webkit-transform: none !important; 
    z-index: 1 !important; 
}
```

This issue was only present in Android using Chrome. On IOS the issue was not there

Comment: some explanation on what was causing he issue would be very helpful

Comment: I still dont know what was causing this. My guess is that has something to do with Bootstrap and the browsers engines itself, maybe some behaviour of the .nav-collapse. Anyhow, it seems that the -webkit-transfrom was the main issue, it seemed to me that that rule was "hiding" the elements. And the z-index trick did the rest.